# How to display .pdf file in modal window?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

I have `.pdf` and `.html` file on the server. I want to display`.pdf` file in modal window. Currently, my .html file is working fine.

`@item.ExampleUrl` gives me `.pdf` and `.html` file.

Please suggest me how to populate `.pdf` in the modal.

Please have a look on `.pdf` file in the screenshot

[image]

Script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.openExamplefile').on('click', function () {
                debugger;
                var url = $(this).attr("data-url"); //page url  
                if (url == "/files/examples/" || url == "/files/examples/ ") {
                    alert("There is no html file exists!")
                }
                else {
                    $("#PedigreesSireRacingModal").load(url, function () {
                      $("#PedigreesSireRacing").modal({ show: true });
                    });
                }

            });

        });
```

Controller

```
public FileResult Download(string FileName)
{           
            return File("~/files/examples/" + FileName, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(FileName),FileName);
}
```

My modal

```
<button id="ButtontoLink" type="button" class="openExamplefile" 
     data-url="/files/examples/@item.ExampleUrl">Example</button>

<div class="modal" id="PedigreesSireRacing" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:1250px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><label id="ProductName"></label>  </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="PedigreesSireRacingModal" class="modal-body racing">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used variant of one of the solutions on stack overflow. Though I wanted the button on my webpage to access a search facility in a modal popup.

The PDF file is a searchable document from 1957 of some 2,270 entries of soldiers names and grave locations.

The only bug I have seen so far is the Chrome doesnt display the find in document magnifying glass icon like Edge and Moazilla but does still support CTRL-F searches.

The calling routine from the main page is :

```
<a href="https://ratsoftobruk.com.au/war-graves/SEARCH.html" target="_blank"
  onclick="window.open('https://web-server/sub-folder/SEARCH.html','SEARCHER','resizable,height=900,width=1200'); return false;">Search Grave<br>Register</a>
```

The code for SEARCH.html for the modal is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tobruk War Cemetery Vol 1 & 2</title>
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                        <embed src="https://web-server/directory/name-of-the-pdf.pdf" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="700px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a add a `<enbed src="">` into you `<div>`.
Also it **works in modals**.
Example;

```
<div>
<embed src="https://YourPdf" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="400px">
</div>
```

or in Modal:

```
<div id="YouModal"> <embed src="https://YourPdf" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="400px">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<embed>` tag inside your modal like so

```
<button id="ButtontoLink" type="button" class="openExamplefile" 
     data-url="/files/examples/@item.ExampleUrl">Example</button>

<div class="modal" id="PedigreesSireRacing" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:1250px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><label id="ProductName"></label></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="PedigreesSireRacingModal" class="modal-body racing">
                <embed src="/path/to/pdf_file.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code is not working. I am getting the same output which I have included here. I think i have to do something in JQuery as this gives me the `url`.

Comment: are you getting the real path to the file?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the path `var url = $(this).attr("data-url");`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to embed the pdf inside the modal? Like this:

```
<embed src="pdf-example.pdf" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="400px">
```

Comment: This code is not working. I am getting the same output. Please provide me proper solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FileStreamResult` as return type instead of `FileResult`:

```
public ActionResult Download(string fileName)
{
    var stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/files/examples/" + fileName), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");

    return result;
}
```

Then put an `<embed>` tag inside modal `<div>` element as PDF placeholder:

```
<div id="PedigreesSireRacingModal" class="modal-body racing">
    <embed src="@Url.Action("Download", "ControllerName", new { fileName = "FileName.pdf" })" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf">
    </embed>
</div>
```

**Update 1:**

Since you can return either HTML or PDF format, put a check against file extension and use proper content type in both controller and `embed`/`object` tag:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Download(string fileName)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/files/examples/" + fileName);
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);

    var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, contentType);

    return result;
}
```

**View**

```
<!-- example if using viewmodel property -->
<object data="@Url.Action("Download", "ControllerName", new { fileName = Model.FileName })" width="100%" height="100%">
</object>

<embed src="@Url.Action("Download", "ControllerName", new { fileName = Model.FileName })" width="100%" height="100%" type="@Model.ContentType">
</embed>
```

As a side note, try to use `Content-Disposition` response header setting in controller action method to ensure file type is properly set:

```
var contentDisposition = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = fileName,
    Inline = true
};

Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
```

Comment: My network path is not working now. So, I will try and see tomorrow. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I have `.html` file as well so now every time your code is sending it in `public ActionResult Download(string fileName)
{` section. I am getting both `.html` and `.pdf`. I think, I have to check if the file is .pdf` then send that to your code else simply display the `.html` file. How can we do this. please guide me on my this issues as well.

Comment: Well, I think you need to perform check if the passed file extension is HTML or PDF, and use `object` or `iframe` tag which can render both of them by different MIME type.

Comment: Where to write this view code as I want to display the report in model. If I write this code in the modal then how should I modify my JQuery script. Please suggest me.

Comment: As far as I read your question, you have 2 choices: using jQuery AJAX with file name as `data` parameter to render `embed`/`object` tag containing file content at modal dialog, or pass file name and content type through viewmodel properties while returning view from GET request with pre-applied `embed`/`object` tag in modal dialog. The next step depends in which option that you're chosen.

Comment: I am following your code so please suggest me where to put this view element in my code. Also also how to open that file in modal.

Comment: Please suggest me how to display the file in modal. I am struggling this since yesterday. Please guide me. Thank you.