# Display PDF file in modal window using PartialView

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, modal-dialog

In my Asp.Net Core (MVC, core 2.2) I use a sort of a generic modal pop-up throughout the website.

In the Layout page I have the basic code for the modal:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modalGeneric" role="dialog"></div>
```

```js
function showGenericModal(event) {
    var src = event.target || event.srcElement;

    // find the parent that contains proper decorations
    var url = $(src).closest("*[data-url]").data('url');

    // trigger an HTTP GET
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        // fill content and show modal
        $('#modalGeneric').html(data);
        $('#modalGeneric').modal('show');
    });
}
```

and I can then call it (open) with a link like this:

```html
<a class="ml-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Predogled" 
    href="@Url.Action("PdfPartial", "ZavarovalnePolice", new { id = item.Id })"      
    onclick="showGenericModal(event);">
</a>
```

That calls an action from the controller and opens the required PartialView that has the rest of the modal code. And it works.

Following the examples from this post: [How to display .pdf file in modal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151166/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-modal-window) I want to show a PDF in my modal pop-up.

So, I added this two Actions to my Controller:

```cs
public IActionResult PdfPartial(int id)
{
    ViewBag.Id = id;
    return PartialView("_PartialDocumentPreview");
}

public async Task<IActionResult> ShowModalDocument(int id)
{
    var file = _docs.GetDocument(id);

    file.Contents = await _docs.Download(doc);

    var contentDisposition = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = file.Title,
        Inline = true
    };

    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());

    var memory = new MemoryStream(file.Contents);
    return File(memory.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
}
```

and the PartialView ("_PartialDocumentPreview"):

```html
<div class="modal-dialog" >
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">          
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="PdfModal">
            <embed  src="@Url.Action("ShowModalDocument", "ZavarovalnePolice", 
            new { id = @ViewBag.Id })" type="application/pdf" 
            style="width:100%; height:100%"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" 
            data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The PDF opens, but not in a modal pop-up, rather as a new page (with a url like: https://localhost:123/ZavarovalnePolice/PdfPartial/1.

What I'm doing wrong that it doesn't open as a pop-up?

EDIT (as per @Rena suggestion in the answer below) -
I just changed the `href` to `data-url` and it works:

```html
<a class="ml-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Predogled" 
    data-url="@Url.Action("PdfPartial", "ZavarovalnePolice", new { id = item.Id })"    
    onclick="showGenericModal(event);">
</a>
```

Comment: Could you share more details about your controller and entire view code?About what is your `_docs` and  `item.id`.

Comment: `_docs` is a repository with methods that return document (attachment) data from the DB and `item.id` is the ID of the document from the view model. I'll try your workaround from below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'm doing wrong that it doesn't open as a pop-up?

That is because you add `href` in your `<a>` link,it would get into the `PdfPartial` action by default,no need to add it if you use jQuery.

Here is a simple workaround like below:

1.View:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalGeneric" role="dialog"></div>
<a class="ml-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Predogled" href="#">show the pdf</a>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var url ="@Url.Action("PdfPartial", "ZavarovalnePolice", new { id = 1 })";
            console.log(url);
            $('.ml-1').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#modalGeneric').html(data);
                        $('#modalGeneric').modal('show');
                    }
                })
            });
        });           
    </script>
}
```

2.Controller:

```
public IActionResult PdfPartial(int id)
{
    ViewBag.Id = id;
    return PartialView("_PartialDocumentPreview");
}

public async Task<IActionResult> ShowModalDocument(int id)
{
    string filePath = "~/file/test.pdf";
    var contentDisposition = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = "test.pdf",
        Inline = true
    };
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
    return File(filePath, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
}
```

3.pdf would pop-up so small by using default css style,you could add css style like below in your main view not partial view:

```
<style>
.modal-dialog {
    height: 90%; /* = 90% of the .modal-backdrop block = %90 of the screen */
}
.modal-content {
    height: 100%; /* = 100% of the .modal-dialog block */
}
#PdfModal {
    height: 100%;
}
```

4.Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. The firs sentence of your answer was the solution ( _That is because you add href in your <a> link,it would get into the PdfPartial action by default,no need to add it if you use jQuery_). So, I just changed the `href` to `data-url` and everything works great!